# Why did I get a "There's been a change to your Google account" message and password reprompt?

Tags: google-account, security

I got a message on my mobile today:

> "There's been a change to your Google account"

along with a prompt to re-enter my password.

Could someone be using my account or is this a known issue?

Comment: some say it could be loosely related to this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1139 (Oauth tokens might have been compromised)

Comment: Your description is slightly different, but beware of a late 2016/early 2017 very successful and rapidly spreading Google Account phishing scam, related in particular to Google Docs. One article describing it is [Google Gmail Phishing](http://fortune.com/2017/01/18/google-gmail-scam-phishing/). The key giveaway is seeing "data:text/" at the start of the url that should show when you hover over the password prompt.

Comment: I got a very official looking notification bearing this message on my (Android) phone. After going through my entire Google Dashboard, I determined it was almost definitely real, and logged in, in both my accounts. I REALLY hope this wasn't a virus on my phone. It was acting through the Play Store app, so if this is illegitimate, it'll be hard to get rid of.

Answer (score 41):

It looks like this is a known issue, and Google is on top of it.

From the [product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!category-topic/gmail/Kfsx8YjqAS4):

> We've gotten reports about some users being signed out of their accounts unexpectedly. We're investigating, but not to worry: there is no indication that this is connected to any phishing or account security threats.
>
> Please try to sign-in again at [accounts.google.com](http://accounts.google.com/) and if you cannot remember your password, please use this link ([g.co/recover](http://g.co/recover)) to recover your password. If you use 2-Step Verification, there may have been a delay in receiving your SMS code. Please try again or use [backup codes](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538).

Essentially the same message is currently displayed at the top of the [Accounts Help: Can't sign in to your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620) page.

Also, from [@google on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Google/status/834993667911737345):

> We know some of you had issues signing in today. Please try again now. Rest easy -- your account's security was not affected.

See also:

- Information Security Stack Exchange: [Google account verification request](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/152252/104808)
- [Google accounts are on the fritz but nobody is getting hacked](http://www.androidcentral.com/google-accounts-are-fritz-nobody-getting-hacked)
- [PSA: If you were signed out of your Google account tonight, don’t worry](https://9to5google.com/2017/02/23/google-unexpected-sign-out/)
- [Google is having issues with account sign-in, resulting in errors with Android devices, OnHub, and Wifi](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/02/24/google-issues-account-sign-resulting-errors-android-devices-onhub-wifi/)
- [Google Users Unexpectedly Signed Out of Accounts](http://www.pcmag.com/news/351954/google-users-unexpectedly-signed-out-of-accounts)

Comment: Also apparently some have had settings reset, so you should check for that

Comment: @David: OnHub and WiFi routers, specifically.

Comment: Funny. Are they really using a 'g.co/recover' link in their official message? How are users supposed to trust this kind of domain name?

Comment: g.co is Google's official URL shortener. Only they can use it.